# ASP.net core web service - client-driven paging versus server-driven paging - what is meant by this client-driven paging comment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web-services, pagination

I am trying to implement paging for my Web Service and in my research I ran across this article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/using-skiptoken-for-paging-in-asp-net-odata-and-asp-net-core-odata/

In this article, the author, Kanish, says the following about Client-driven paging:

```
Example: GET ~/Products/$skip=70&$top=10
```

*However, this is problematic if the data is susceptible to change. In case of a deletion in between two requests for consecutive pages, a record will be served in both the requests.*

Two programmers today (myself and a co-worker) have been scratching our heads over what is meant by this and some googling doesn't find me anything to elaborate on what was meant.

Trying to think it through, I was testing with pages of 5.  The current page had 111, 112, 113, 114, 115.  The next page was 116, 117, 118, 119, 120.

Before I moved to the next page, I deleted 115 and 116 in the database.  When I got to that next page I saw 118, 119, 120, 121, and 122 now.  Which is my *expectation* being that 115, 116 were deleted (so no 115 and 116, 117 moves up to the prev page, and we get 121 and 122 in place of 116 and 117).  And when I go back to the previous page it's: 111, 112, 113, 114, 117 (117 moved up from the next page).

Can someone explain what is meant by this glossed-over comment?  And what would be different about some server-driven implementation?

EDIT: I was testing against a simple controller in an ASP.NET core 3 environment utilizing the Entity Framework and using this odata enabled end-point:

```
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<AgntTypes>> GetAgentTypes()
    {
        string sql = GetTheDefaultQuery();

        IQueryable<AgntTypes> agntTypes = _agentContext.AgntTypes.FromSqlRaw(sql).AsNoTracking();

        return Ok(agntTypes.AsQueryable());
    }
```

Comment: We can't tell you because you haven't told us any details about the system or application you were using that paged the items as-you-expected. From my perspective it looks like your application already does "anchor" the page-numbers so they're safe from mutation. But if you repro it  in an application with naive/trivial paging logic then it's easy to reproduce.

Comment: @Dai - My apologies, but I thought the link to the article itself was enough to go on, no?  As for the details of the system or application, it's a simple Controller (we are using ASP.NET core 3.1) that returns an IQueryable.  We are also using Entity Framework.  I'll post the simple end-point I was testing against.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You aren't really using EF in that example: you're executing a pass-through query from `string sql` - and you haven't shown us what's in `sql` - that's a very important detail. Also you **should not** use an `IQueryable<T>` as a model-object (for too many reasons to list). You need to materialize your data using `.ToList` first.

Comment: Your `GetAgentTypes()` action does not have any paging parameters...

Comment: @Dai - Lets take a step back, this was never meant to be a critique of any code I wrote.  I was just trying to understand what the author of that article meant by the comment he made in the article.  So I tried to figure out what he meant.  Being that he used some example using odata, I quickly put together an endpoint that would return an iqueryable to allow for delayed execution of the sql statement.  Otherwise, if we .ToList first and then applied odata after it got to the client, we would pull back the superset first at the server then the odata top/skip is applied at the client 4 subset.

Comment: @Dai So I would think if you are using top/skip, and in that case skip IS your page number, you need it to be iqueryable, so again it doesn’t retrieve the superset first before the odata is applied.  But this is where im trying to figure out what exactly he meant by client driven, does it look something like that, and what does he mean by the comment he said.  How is it problematic as he says?  How can I test to see this or explained in a way I can understand?  Thank you.

Comment: One other thing, that being said, we were going in the direction of odata on an iqueryable, to take advantage of the deferred execution and to only pull back the subset as I mentioned using odata (with guards to ensure top/skip were used).  And it seemed fairly quick, but when I read that article it gave me pause.  But Im really interested in understanding what he meant.  Thank you again!

Comment: If you’re using some kind OData components in ASP.NET to wrap or handle your IEnumerable or IQueryable result then that would explain it - but you didn’t mention that in your post at all. From the code you’ve posted it looks like a conventional ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WebAPI action method without any use of OData-related libraries/features. Here over the internet we cannot automagically know how your code works or behaves without a way to reproduce the behaviour you’re describing and you haven’t posted a _minimum reproducible example_. Your edit put “Odata-enabled endpoint” but didn’t clarify.

Comment: @Dai - I admit I'm a little confused.  Why would I need a reproducible example?  I'm not saying this to be silly, but what I'm saying is that I read an article (which I linked to) and then pulled a quote from him.  I was having trouble understanding what he meant, from his quote, in his article, so I linked to the article.  Again, I'm not trying to be silly, but wouldn't reading the first part of the article where he said that be enough?  Because that's what I was asking about.  The only example from that article was: GET ~/Products/$skip=70&$top=10, so I assumed he used odata on IQueryable

Comment: @Dai - So, I don't have code that I'm using.  I'm trying to figure out an approach for us, so that we do have code.  When he says something like: However, this is problematic ... I was looking to understand what it was that he felt was problematic.  That's it.  Again, I don't have code that I've personally written.  Any code I presented ... and you asked for ... was what I thought he was possibly doing.  I thought I made that clear.  In conclusion, my focus is on the comment he said, in his article, not any actual code I produced.  That's why I don't have a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: automagically. love that unwarranted and unnecessary snark.  especially when I wasn't wrong.